# Methods to avoid hard-coding file paths in Python

Tags: python

Working with scientific data, specifically climate data, I am constantly hard-coding paths to data directories in my Python code. Even if I were to write the most extensible code in the world, the hard-coded file paths prevent it from ever being truly portable. I also feel like having information about the file system of your machine coded in your programs could be security issue.

What solutions are out there for handling the configuration of paths in Python to avoid having to code them out explicitly?

Comment: How about environment variables?

Comment: How about command line arguments? Configuration files?

Comment: You could try taking user input for the data.  So when the program is run it requests the user to type their own file path and file name.  Then you don't need to worry about hard coding.  If this is a solution you'd want, I could try and write out some basic stuff explaining how it works soon-ish.

Comment: @reubano On systems at work where I'm not the administrator (aka all of them) I can't guarantee the presence of particular environment variables. I suppose in an __init__ module I could use os.getenv() to set environment variables temporarily, but that again involves hard coding them somewhere in my project.

Comment: See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/271565/hard-coded-file-paths-solution

Comment: @J0hn user input through `raw_input()`, or through command line args? Only problem with `raw_input()` is users could maliciously enter file paths that, given knowledge about what the code does with those paths, could cause problems.

Comment: thanks for the link to that post @mkrieger1

Answer (score 3):

One of the solution rely on using configuration files.

You can store all your path in a json file like so :

```
{
     "base_path" : "/home/bob/base_folder",
     "low_temp_area_path" : "/home/bob/base/folder/low_temp"
}
```

and then in your python code, you could just do :

```
import json

with open("conf.json") as json_conf : 
    CONF = json.load(json_conf)
```

and then you can use your path (or any configuration variable you like) like so :

```
print "The base path is {}".format(CONF["base_path"])
```

Comment: Depends on the number of argument you need to parse and if they are mandatory or not.

Answer (score 3):

First off its always good practise to add a main function to go with each class to test that class or functions in the file. Along with this you determine the current working directory. This becomes incredibly important when running python from a cron job or from a directory that is not the current working directory. No JSON files or environment variables are then needed and you will obtain interoperation across Mac, RHEL and Debian distributions.

This is how you do it, and it will work on windows also if you use '\' instead of '/' (if that is even necessary, in your case).

```
if "__main__" == __name__:
    workingDirectory  = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0])
```

As you can see when you run your command, the working directory is calculated if you provide a full path or relative path, meaning it will work in a cron job automatically.

After that if you want to work with data that is stored in the current directory use:

```
fileName = os.path.join( workingDirectory, './sub-folder-of-current-directory/filename.csv' )
fp       = open( fileName,'r')
```

or in the case of the above working directory (parallel to your project directory):

```
fileName = os.path.join( workingDirectory, '../folder-at-same-level-as-my-project/filename.csv' )
fp       = open( fileName,'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are many ways around this, but here is what I would do:

1. Create a JSON config file with all the paths I need defined.
2. For even more portability, I'd have a default path where I look for this config file but also have a command line input to change it.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion passing arguments from command line would be best solution. You should take a look at [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) . This allows you to create nice way to handle arguments from the command line. for example:
`myDataScript.py /home/userName/datasource1/`

Comment: I like argparse, but all of the code required to set up the argument parser clutters up the code, in my opinion. But this is a perfectly valid option I always forget about. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that you can pass file contents as arguments. `cat fileWithPaths | xargs python myDataScript.py`. This way every line from `fileWithPaths` will be seperate element in `sys.argv` list